# SQL- Average all transactions that match id

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, sql-update, average

I am using SQLite and attempting to find the average transaction price of a good by ID. I am attempting to update the A.avg_price with the average price of all transactions in the quarter for that specific company (identified by id) from Table B. I attempted the below query, but it ran for over an hour with no luck-- so I imagine I did something inefficiently. I am new to SQL, so this help is greatly appreciated!

`UPDATE "Table_A" AS A Set "avg_price" = (SELECT AVG ("price") FROM "Table_B" AS B WHERE A."id" = B."id")`

```
      TABLE_A
```

| company id | avg_price |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | NULL |
| 2. | NULL |

```
    TABLE_B
```

| company id | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1/1/23 | $10 |
| 1. | 1/4/23 | $12 |
| 2. | 1/4/23 | $14 |
| 2. | 1/10/23 | $2 |
| 3. | 1/5/23 | $15 |
| 1. | 1/4/23 | $8 |
| 3. | 1/20/23 | $30 |

Expected Result for Table A
| company id |  avg_price |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 1.         | $10        |
| 2.         | $8         |
| 3.         | $22.5      |

Comment: You should research window functions. You can do AVG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id) AS AVG_PRICE_BY_COMPANY ... do it with select first until you figure out whats going on, before you work on an update.

Comment: SELECT "company id", avg(price) FROM Table_B GROUP BY "company id" will get you the average price for every company. For writing the average prices to TABLE_A you may want to look for UPSERT.

Answer (score 1):

The query updates the "avg_price" column in Table A to contain the average transaction price for each company. It does this by first calculating the average price for each company in Table B and storing these averages in a temporary table called "B." Then, it matches the companies in Table A with the corresponding averages in "B" using the company ID. Finally, it updates the "avg_price" in Table A with the calculated averages, ensuring that each company's average price is correctly reflected in Table A.

```
UPDATE "Table_A" AS A
SET "avg_price" = B.avg_price
FROM (
    SELECT "id", AVG("price") AS avg_price
    FROM "Table_B"
    GROUP BY "id"
) AS B
WHERE A."id" = B."id";
```